# Declaring an array inside typedef struct

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to declare an array inside a typedef struct like this:

```
typedef struct Node {
     Node[] arr = new Node[25];
};
```

But I am getting an error saying "expected an identifier" and that arr "expected a ';'. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: In C++, brackets in array initialization are placed after the identifer both on left and right-hand sides, all the time. `Node arr[25]`

Comment: Do you really want to allocate 25 `Node`s in a `Node`?

Comment: I tried that before but when I do that, it says "incompatible type is not allowed" underneath the arr and underneath the second Node it says "the generated default constructor for "Node" cannot be used in an initializer for its own data member"

Comment: @songyuanyao I want each node to have an array of 25 nodes

Comment: @Chris Then each of 25 nodes also have their own 25 nodes?

Comment: I suppose so, I might be thinking about this incorrectly. I'm trying to make a dictionary trie so I thought about having each node have an array and have a string representing where it is in the trie. I meant to type 26 for the size lol

Comment: @Chris You'd better reconsider the design, at least the code you showed won't work, it tempts to cause an infinite construction of `Node`. And `Node` is not complete type until the end of the class definnition, so you can't do `new Node[25]` inside the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

you can act like this

```
struct Node {
    static const int arr_size = 25;
    Node* arr;
    Node() { arr = new Node[arr_size]; }
    ~Node() { delete[] arr; }
};
```

you re not allowed initialzie non const int varizbles inside the class;

---

and do you understand, that creating a node variable will call stack overflow ? 
Each node contains 25 nodes where each node contains 25 nodes ... etc

---

i think you wanted something like this

```
struct Node {
    static const int arr_size = 25;
    Node* arr[arr_size];
};
```